# Tibble error (Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.)

Tags: text-mining, tidymodels

I have been trying to run the updated code provided at [GitHub](https://github.com/dgrtwo/tidy-text-mining/blob/master/05-document-term-matrices.Rmd) by Dr. Silge in "Text Mining with R: A tidy approach" for the example "Mining Financial Articles".

```
library(tm.plugin.webmining)
library(purrr)
company <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook",
             "Twitter", "IBM", "Yahoo", "Netflix")
symbol  <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", 
             "TWTR", "IBM", "YHOO", "NFLX")
download_articles <- function(symbol) {
  WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource(paste0("NASDAQ:", symbol)))
}
stock_articles <- tibble(company = company,
                         symbol = symbol) %>%
  mutate(corpus = map(symbol, download_articles))
```

However, after running the tibble function, it gives me the following error:

> Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
> Size 8: Existing data.
> • Size 9: Column `symbol`.
> ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tm.plugin.webmining package has not been updated in a long time and no longer connected to the resources it needs, unfortunately. The code in the book still runs because we recorded what this package *did* return at the time that we wrote the book; the book uses that older result. We are tracking [this needed update on GitHub](https://github.com/dgrtwo/tidy-text-mining/issues/62) and thinking about a good replacement.